# Create ReadStream from api request having audio gzip audio buffer in express js

Tags: node.js, express, zlib, multer

How we can create read stream from file uploaded buffer something like below

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const multer = require('zlib');
const fs= require('fs')
router.post('/upload/:recordId', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const buffer=req.file.buffer // this is test.gz file buffer
    let write;
    var r = fs.createReadStream(buffer);// this line is not working
    var z = zlib.createGunzip();
    var w = fs.createWriteStream(write); // this line is not working
    r.pipe(z).pipe(w);
    res.status(204).json({ statusDescription: '204 No Content' });
  } catch (ex) {
    next(ex);
  }
});
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, `stream` module is used.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var r = fs.createReadStream(buffer);
```

#### To:

```
const stream = require("stream");
var r = new stream.PassThrough().end(buffer);
```

And also, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
const multer = require('zlib');
```

#### To:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
```

### Reference:

- [Class: stream.PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.